# Migrate from VirtualBox to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtualbox

I've some in house testing VM's, primarily win10 that I host on Virtualbox, I'd like to move these to GCP but there doesn't' seem to be a simple way to do this.

anyone got any advice?

Comment: A quick scan of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks) seems to indicate that Windows 10 is not a supported OS for importing existing disk images.

Comment: The below answer is good. I’m not sure why your question was downvoted so I’ve upvoted it now. You weren’t asking if it was supported, you were asking if it was possible effectively. Happy questioning!

Comment: @TimothyFrew ServerFault is about [managing information technology systems in a business environment](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and running a platform that is not supported is not a recommended business strategy.  Hence the implied: there is very good reason that doesn't work, rethink your OS choice and instead run your windows applications on a Windows server operating system that is supported.

Comment: @HBruijn doesn’t mean it’s a bad question. I just take the view that if we can help then we should. Although having said this... I should mention that when the VMs are transferred over to GCP... the licenses will no longer be valid unless they’re VLK.

Comment: @HBruijn not about rethinking something, if you need a specific testing environment, then you need a specific testing environment, windows 10 is probably the most common os In the world, all I Was asking if it was possible to migrate to GCP, rather than add a VM hypervisor and migrate to that

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 is not supported in GCP, in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks#supported_operating_systems) you can see the OS supported in GCP and only can be Windows Server for Microsoft, if you set another image maybe with windows server in your local machine with VB or other supported OS (Linux) then you can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks) to migrate your local VMs to GCP, however be aware of the [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks#limitations).

I hope this helps you out.